# Build VOIP phone callls betwenn SIP client and analog/mobile phone

Tags: networking, protocols, sip, voip, gateway

I've Built a VOIP Network for my House using  Asterisk as server and SIP softphone as client. Everthink is going good  and i can call all SIP client of my VOIP Network.
Now I have no idea how  to call an extern mobile phone  or analog phone .
I've heard something about Gateway to access to another network.

any hehp woulb be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy SIP trunking providers service for that. Find out all the sip trunking providers who have voip termination in your country. You have to create SIP trunk into your asterisk server and call mobile phone and analog phones through their trunk. Alternatively you can also buy digium PRI cards and configure your own T1, E1 PRI. You have to buy T1,E1 PRI service from Telco operators such as in India there are Airtel, Reliance who is providing PRI service.

Some of the SIP trunking providers are such as
Callbox and Rapidvox and Twilio

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for this purpose, you need a VoIP GSM gateway, or an ATA device or a VoIP Service provider connection. As you are interested in VoIP GSM gateways, you will need a device like Cisco SPA3102 VoIP phone adapter.

> The SPA3102 features the ability to connect standard telephones and
>   fax machines to IP-based data networks with the additional benefit of
>   an integrated connection for legacy telephone network hop-on, hop-off
>   applications. SPA3102 users will be able to leverage their broadband
>   phone service more than ever by automatically routing local calls from
>   mobile phones and land lines over to VoIP service providers and vice
>   versa.

(Source: [Analog adapter with FXS and FXO port](http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_254-analog-gateway-voip.html))